# Can a CDL driver take on a second job driving a 10k or lower transport job during hometime?

Tags: transportation

im looking for a second job (non forced dispatch) for when im on hometime (which is 2 days a week maybe more). i drive a tractor trailer for 5 days a week doing regional. im looking to see if i can do this other job which is a type of job where Hours of Service isnt applied while im on a 34 hour reset on my main job. 
the second job im talking about has a truck with a gvwr of 6,000 lbs, no trailer involved. 
Google the Youtube channel "The Gator Chronicles", he does the truck bed style hotshot trucking.
im going to be an owner operator for this second job. im an employee at the CDL job.
Sooo, i hoping since the hotshot job i want to do doesnt have an ELD requirement by itself that it wont interfere with my HOS of CDL job.
Any thoughts?

Comment: In what country?

Comment: United States  !!